# MLA-8: How to cite information with multiple sources

Tags: citations, mla

> No abstinence-only-until-marriage program has been shown to help teens delay the initiation of sex or to protect themselves when they do initiate sex.

This is directly taken from [advocates for youth](http://www.advocatesforyouth.org/component/content/article/450-effective-sex-education), and they cite it as:

> No abstinence-only-until-marriage program has been shown to help teens delay the initiation of sex or to protect themselves when they do initiate sex.[8,9,10,11]

Where 8,9,10,11 refer to these sources:

> 8. Santelli J et al. Abstinence and abstinence-only education: a review of U.S. policies and programs. Journal of Adolescent Health 2006; 38(1):72-81.
> 9. Hauser D. Five Years of Abstinence-Only-Until-Marriage Education: Assessing the Impact [Title V State Evaluations] Washington, DC: Advocates for Youth, 2004.
> 10. Committee on HIV Prevention Strategies in the United States, Institute of Medicine. No Time to Lose: Getting More from HIV Prevention. Washington, DC: National Academy Press, 2000.
> 11. Society for Adolescent Medicine. Abstinence-only education policies and programs: a position paper of the Society for Adolescent Medicine. Journal of Adolescent Health 2006; 38(1):83-87.

The [MLA In-Text Citations](https://www.roanestate.edu/owl/MLA-In-Text-Citations.htm) page doesn't have information on how to cite a paraphrased piece of information from multiple sources. If I plan to write:

> No abstinence only until programs have been shown to correlate with an elder age of first engagement of sex, or an increase in contraceptive use.

How should this be cited with all 4 sources? Should I just pick what I think is most reliable? Should I use advocates for youth's article? Is there any standard way to cite in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually relatively simple. This information is taken from [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/2/) (a really great website for MLA problems).

> To cite multiple sources in the same parenthetical reference, separate the citations by a semi-colon:
>   . . . as has been discussed elsewhere (Burke 3; Dewey 21).

You stick all your citations between two parentheses and separate them by semi-colons.